# Modify response header / body / status code with lambda integration in Serveless framework 1.5

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I use Serveless framework 1.5.

With "lambda-proxy integration", modifying response header / body / status code is very easy.

```
callback(null, {
  status: 200,
  headers: {
    'STRING_VALUE': 'STRING_VALUE'
  },
  body: 'STRING_VALUE'
});
```

But I want to use path_info value, so I use serverless.yml like below:

```
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
  events:
    - http:
        path: hello/{hi}
        method: get
        integration: lambda
        request:
          parameters:
            paths:
              hi: true
```

To get path_info setting must use "lambda integration".
But also I want to modify response header / body / status code of response.
How should I make setting to modify these response values with "lambda integration"?

Regards,

==Postscript==

After submitting question, I found the document:
https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#lambda-integration

According to this, body can be customized:

```
        response:
          headers:
            Content-Type: "'text/html'"
          template: $input.path('$')
```

But, for response header, document says:

```
        response:
          headers:
            Content-Type: integration.response.header.Content-Type
            Cache-Control: "'max-age=120'"
```

I make setting same as above, and code handler.js like below:

```
  callback(null, {
    header: {'Content-Type': 'image/png'}
  });
```

though header content_type didn't become 'image/png'.
How can I modify response header dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To get path_info setting must use "lambda integration".

You can access the path parameters using Lambda Proxy integration by using:

```
event["pathParameters"]["id"]
```

Just remember to check `event["pathParameters"] !== null` first if there's a chance your Lambda can be called without any path parameters.

Comment: Really? Thank you for information, it was changed recent? If my memory is not poor, I think at least version 1.3 could not use PATH_INFO from lambda-proxy...Thank you!

Comment: I checked it works.. I spent many times to struggle with lambda integration, it was no means.. Anyway thank you!

Answer (score 2):

and I found the answer of my question by myself:

For changing header, serverless.yml setting must be:

```
      response:
        headers:
          Content-Type: "integration.response.body.headers.Content-Type"
        template: $input.path('$.body')
```

and responding code must be:

```
    callback(null, {
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'},
      body: body
    });
```

One confusing point is, "$ in response template" and "integration.response.body in setting of header mapping" are same meaning.
So, "$.body" is same with "integration.response.body.body".

To Changing Status code, we should use Error object.

```
const status = err ? new Error('[404] Not found') : null;
callback(status, {
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'},
    body: body
});
```